# why can't I have a for loop inside an anonymous function in scala?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

when I try to run the following code:

```
val anonFunc = (x: Pos): List[Pos] => {for(i <- 1 to 10){ println(i)}
```

I get the following error:

```
 illegal start of declaration
```

and I have no idea why.
This code is used inside a function

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ? This isn't valid scala

Comment: Why isn't this valid scala? I'm creating a anonymous function and storing it using val?

Comment: No you're not. For example, here is a anonymous function : `var inc = (x:Int) => x+1`. What should be the parameters of your function and what is supposed to be returned ?

Comment: There are several things wrong with it, but it is hard to help unless you state what it is you want to achieve with it

Comment: `{ x: Pos => for(i <- 1 to 10) println(i) }` is the right syntax. Not that it makes very much sense ... but it will compile.

Answer (score 2):

(1) There two ways to ensure correct return type of anonymous function that I know:

```
val f = (x: Int) => { x + 1 }: Double

val f: Int => Double = x => x + 1
```

(2) Your `for` comprehension will return `Unit` as it's written, not `List[Pos]`. To return something real you need to use `yield`:

```
val anonFunc = (x: Pos) => { for(i <- 1 to 10) yield(x) }: List[Pos]
```

but as you do this you will notice that compiler doesn't like `List` as a return type because what `for` returns is `IndexedSeq`, not `List`. So you need to convert it explicitly:

```
val anonFunc = (x: Pos) => { for(i <- 1 to 10) yield(x) }.toList: List[Pos]
```